# Hash function for searching, is that feasible?

Tags: sorting, hash, binary-search

I have a set of sorted values $\left\{a_j \right\}_{1 \leq j \leq n}$, suppose now a number $x$ is given and we would like to find out the index $j$ such that $a_j \leq x < a_{j+1}$ (you can assume always $- a_1 =  a_n = +\infty$). I could find such index with a binary search on the lower bound (which would take $O(\log n)$). However I wonder if a search using some kind of hash function could be used to speed up the search, I think is a kind of similar problem, if not the same.

Comment: I don't understand. How would a hash function speed up anything here? Do you want to hash the $a_j$?

Comment: no, I want the $j$. So maybe there's some kind of hash function that maps $a_j \leq x < a_{j+1}$ into $j$, which would require $O(1)$, assuming no collision.

Comment: It wouldn't be a uniform hashing, assume also that all the numbers are integers.

Comment: In that case the hash function itself will have to depend on the $a_j$ (in all standard uses of hashing, only the data in the hash table depends on the input, not the functions).

Comment: @md5, what function?